# How to find adjacent lines on a regular 3D grid in python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, geometry, distance

I have the coordinate of a bunch of points and want to create surfaces out of them in a python package. I want to arrange my data before importing them into the package. Points are coming from a regular grid. Firstly, I am creating lines based on the location of points. In this step I just define which point numbers create my lines. My input data is:

```py
coord = np.array(
    [[0., 0., 2.], [0., 1., 3.], [0., 2., 2.], [1., 0., 1.], [1., 1., 3.], 
     [1., 2., 1.], [2., 0., 1.], [2., 1., 1.], [3., 0., 1.], [4., 0., 1.]])
```

The figure below shows the numbers of the grid points (gray) and the numbers of the lines (blue and red).

[image: grid]

The lines are modeled through dictionaries, in which the key is the line number, and the value is a tuple with the start and end points numbers:

```py
In [906]: blue_line
Out[906]: {1: (1, 2), 2: (2, 3), 3: (4, 5), 4: (5, 6), 5: (7, 8)}

In [907]: red_line
Out[907]: 
{6: (1, 4),
 7: (2, 5),
 8: (3, 6),
 9: (4, 7),
 10: (5, 8),
 11: (7, 9),
 12: (9, 10)}
```

To learn more about how the lines are generated, check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65626486/how-to-select-some-lines-created-by-points-based-on-their-distances-in-python). The lines that are used to create the surfaces are stored in a list:

```py
surfaces = [(1, 6, 3, 7), (2, 7, 4, 8), (3, 9, 5, 10)]
```

As the last step, I want to find the number of lines which are not used in creating the surfaces or are used but are closer than a limit the the dashed line in the figure above. Again, I have the coordinate of the two points creating that dashed line:

```py
coord_dash = [(2., 2., 2.), (5., 0., 1.)]
adjacency_threshold = 2
```

I want to have these adjacent lines as another list (shown by a red arrow in the figure):

```py
adjacent_lines = [4, 10, 5, 11, 12]
```

I have only this rough idea and do not know how to code it in Python. I can only create line numbers and surfaces and need help to find those close lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining what lines have not been used is straightforward (NumPy's [`setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) comes in handy for this task):

```py
In [924]: all_line = {**blue_line, **red_line}

In [925]: lines = list(all_line.keys())

In [926]: lines
Out[926]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

In [927]: used_lines = np.ravel(surfaces)

In [928]: used_lines
Out[928]: array([ 1,  6,  3,  7,  2,  7,  4,  8,  3,  9,  5, 10])

In [929]: unused_lines = np.setdiff1d(lines, used_lines)

In [930]: unused_lines
Out[930]: array([11, 12])
```

The adjacent lines can be obtained by using NumPy's [`linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html?highlight=linalg%20norm#numpy.linalg.norm):

```py
In [954]: midpoints
Out[954]: 
{1: array([0. , 0.5, 2.5]),
 2: array([0. , 1.5, 2.5]),
 3: array([1. , 0.5, 2. ]),
 4: array([1. , 1.5, 2. ]),
 5: array([2. , 0.5, 1. ]),
 6: array([0.5, 0. , 1.5]),
 7: array([0.5, 1. , 3. ]),
 8: array([0.5, 2. , 1.5]),
 9: array([1.5, 0. , 1. ]),
 10: array([1.5, 1. , 2. ]),
 11: array([2.5, 0. , 1. ]),
 12: array([3.5, 0. , 1. ])}

In [955]: mid_dash = np.array(coord_dash).mean(axis=0)

In [956]: mid_dash
Out[956]: array([3.5, 1. , 1.5])

In [957]: adjacent_lines = []
     ...: for idx, point in midpoints.items():
     ...:     if np.linalg.norm(point - mid_dash) < adjacency_threshold:
     ...:         adjacent_lines.append(idx)

In [958]: adjacent_lines
Out[958]: [5, 11, 12]
```