# how to select some lines created by points based on their distances in python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, distance

I have some lines created by connecting points of a regular grid and want to pair the correct lines to create surfces. This is coordinates of my point array:

```
coord=np.array([[0.,0.,2.], [0.,1.,3.], [0.,2.,2.], [1.,0.,1.], [1.,1.,3.],\
                [1.,2.,1.], [2.,0.,1.], [2.,1.,1.], [3.,0.,1.], [4.,0.,1.]])
```

Then, I created lines by connecting points. My points are from a regular grid. So, I have two perpendicular sets of lines. I called them blue (vertical) and red (horizontal) lines. To do so:

```
blue_line=[]
for ind, i in enumerate (range (len(coord)-1)):
        if coord[i][0]==coord[i+1][0]:
            line=[ind, ind+1]
#             line=[x+1 for x in line]
            blue_line.append(line)
threshold_x = 1.5
threshold_y = 1.5
i, j = np.where((coord[:, 1] == coord[:, np.newaxis, 1]) &
    (abs(coord[:, 0] - coord[:, np.newaxis, 0]) < 1.2 * threshold_y))
# Restrict to where i is before j
i, j = i[i < j], j[i < j]
# Combine and print the indices
red_line=np.vstack([i, j]).T
blue_line=np.array(blue_line)
red_line=np.array(red_line)
all_line=np.concatenate((blue_line, red_line), axis=0)
```

To find the correct lines for creating surfaces, I check the center of each line with the adjacent ones. I start from the first blue line and try if there are other three adjacent lines or not. If I find any line which its center is less than `threshold_x` and also its `x` coordinate is different from that line, I will keep it as a pair. Then I continue searching for adjacent lines with this rule. My fig clearly shows it. First blue line is connected by an arrow to the blue line numbered 3 and also red lines numbered 6 and 7. It is not paired with blue line numbered 2 because they have the same `x` coordinate. I tried the following but it was not successful to do all the things and I coulnot solve it:

```
ave_x=[]
ave_y=[]
ave_z=[]
for ind, line in enumerate (all_line):
    x = (coord[line][0][0]+coord[line][1][0])/2
    ave_x.append (x)
    y = (coord[line][0][1]+coord[line][1][1])/2
    ave_y.append (y)
    z = (coord[line][0][2]+coord[line][1][2])/2
    ave_z.append (z)
avs=np.concatenate((ave_x, ave_y, ave_z), axis=0)
avs=avs.reshape(-1,len (ave_x))
avs_f=avs.T
blue_red=[len (blue_line), len (red_line)]
avs_split=np.split(avs_f,np.cumsum(blue_red))[:-1] # first array is center of 
# blue lines and second is center of red lines
dists=[]
for data in avs_split:
    for ind, val in enumerate (data):
    if ind < len(data):
        for ind in range (len(data)-1):
            squared_dist = np.sum((data[ind]-data[ind+1])**2, axis=0)
            dists.append (squared_dist)
```

In fact I expect my code to give me the resulting list as the pairs of the lines the create three surfaces:

```
[(1, 6, 3, 7), (2, 7, 4, 8), (3, 9, 5, 10)]
```

At the end, I want to find the number of lines which are not used in creating the surfaces or are used but are closer than a limit the the dashed line in my fig. I have the coordinate of the two points creating that dashed line:

```
coord_dash=np.array([[2., 2., 2.], [5., 0., 1.]])
```

adjacency_threshold=2
These line numbers are also:

```
[4, 10, 5, 11, 12]
```

In advance I do appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure my answer is what you are looking for because your question is a bit unclear. To start off I create the blue and red lines as dictionaries, where the keys are the line numbers and the values are tuples with the star and end point numbers. I also create a dictionary `all_mid` where the key is the line number and the value is a pandas `Series` with the coordinates of the mid point.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

coord = np.array([[0.,0.,2.], [0.,1.,3.], [0.,2.,2.], [1.,0.,1.], [1.,1.,3.],
                  [1.,2.,1.], [2.,0.,1.], [2.,1.,1.], [3.,0.,1.], [4.,0.,1.]])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=sorted(coord, key=lambda item: (item[0], item[1], item[2])), 
    columns=['x', 'y', 'z'], 
    index=range(1, len(coord) + 1))

count = 1
blue_line = {}
for start, end in zip(df.index[:-1], df.index[1:]):
    if df.loc[start, 'x'] == df.loc[end, 'x']:
        blue_line[count] = (start, end)
        count += 1

red_line = []
index = df.sort_values('y').index
for start, end in zip(index[:-1], index[1:]):
    if df.loc[start, 'y'] == df.loc[end, 'y']:
        red_line.append((start, end))
red_line = {i + count: (start, end) 
            for i, (start, end) in enumerate(sorted(red_line))}


all_line = {**blue_line, **red_line}
all_mid = {i: (df.loc[start] + df.loc[end])/2 
           for i, (start, end) in all_line.items()}
```

The lines look like this:

```py
In [875]: blue_line
Out[875]: {1: (1, 2), 2: (2, 3), 3: (4, 5), 4: (5, 6), 5: (7, 8)}

In [876]: red_line
Out[876]: 
{6: (1, 4),
 7: (2, 5),
 8: (3, 6),
 9: (4, 7),
 10: (5, 8),
 11: (7, 9),
 12: (9, 10)}
```

Then I define some utility functions:

- `adjacent` returns `True` if the input points are adjacent.
- `left_to_right` returns `True` if the x coordinate of the first point is less than the x coordinate of the second point.
- `connections` returns a dictionary in which the key is a line number and the value is a list with the line numbers connected to it.

```py
def adjacent(p, q, threshold=1):
    dx = abs(p['x'] - q['x'])
    dy = abs(p['y'] - q['y'])
    dxy = np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
    return np.max([dx, dy, dxy]) <= threshold


def left_to_right(p, q):
    return p['x'] < q['x']


def connections(midpoints, it):
    mapping = {}
    for start, end in it:
        if adjacent(midpoints[start], midpoints[end]):
            if left_to_right(midpoints[start], midpoints[end]):
                if start in mapping:
                    if end not in mapping[start]:
                        mapping[start].append(end)
                else:
                    mapping[start] = [end]
    return mapping
```

We are now ready to create a list of lists, in which each sublist has the line numbers that make up a surface:

```py
from itertools import product, combinations

blues = blue_line.keys()
reds = red_line.keys()

blue_to_red = connections(all_mid, product(blues, reds))
blue_to_blue = connections(all_mid, combinations(blues, r=2))

surfaces = []
for start in blue_line:
    red_ends = blue_to_red.get(start, [])
    blue_ends = blue_to_blue.get(start, [])
    if len(red_ends) == 2 and len(blue_ends) == 1:
        surfaces.append(sorted([start] + red_ends + blue_ends))
```

This is what you get:

```py
In [879]: surfaces
Out[879]: [[1, 3, 6, 7], [2, 4, 7, 8], [3, 5, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Dear @Tonechas, I do appreciate your solution and help. I want to firtly create lines and then create surfaces from some points dirtributed regularly in the space. I only can use the coordinate of points to do so. I have a question, are you creating blue and red lines like I was creating them? It is important for me to connect the lines based on the rules I used. And also do you know anyway to extract that line numbers which are not used in any surface and are also in adjacency of the dashed line? Thanks in advance for your help and patience.

Comment: Regarding `blue_line` and `red_line`, we use different methods but the result is the same. The only difference is the naming convention. In your code the points are numbered from 0 to 9, while in my solution the points are numbered from 1 to 10, in accordance with the names displayed in your drawing. If you prefer to use your rules you can generate the lines as in your question and then write `blue_line = {idx+1: (start+1, end+1) for idx, (start, end) in enumerate(blue_line)}` and `red_line = {idx+1: (start+1, end+1) for idx, (start, end) in enumerate(red_line)}`.

Comment: I would recommend you to post a new, simpler question to get help about the second part of your comment. Alternatively you could edit this [duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65614219/how-to-create-surfaces-from-coordinates-of-points-of-a-regular-grid-in-python).

Comment: Dear @Tonechas, thanks for your hint. The pont is that I cannot explain that lines simpler. If I was only looking for line numbers that are not in any surfaces it was simpler but the problem is that I must create surface pairs and then look for that line number.